cannot save key-value data to local Redis server in Java Springboot
this is first time using Redis database, i encounter basic problems
i'm trying to save data to Redis local server but it failed
it seems configuration has not problem but i don't know why
api test has not failed and there's no error messages
but practically cannot save key-value data
enter image description here
enter image description here
@Repository
class RatingRedisRepository (
    private val redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, String>,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper 
) {

    val logger = LogManager.getLogger(RatingController::class.java)!!

    fun saveRating(rating: Rating) {
        val ratingJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rating)
        logger.info(ratingJson.toString())
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("rating:${rating.id}", ratingJson)
    }

}

//controller
 @PostMapping("/save")
    fun saveRating(@RequestBody ratingDTO: RatingDTO): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val rating = ratingMapper.toEntity(ratingDTO)
        logger.info(rating.toString())
        ratingRedisService.saveRating(rating)
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
    }



//mapper
@Service
class RatingMapper : Mapper<RatingDTO, Rating> {

    override fun fromEntity(entity: Rating): RatingDTO = RatingDTO(
        entity.id,
        entity.user_id,
        entity.movie_id,
        entity.rating

    )


    override fun toEntity(domain: RatingDTO): Rating = Rating(
        domain.id,
        domain.user_id,
        domain.movie_id,
        domain.rating

    )
}

configuration file's below
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int port;


    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(host,port);
    }



    @Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListener(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }

}

If you need any additional information, please let me know!
api test has not failed and there's no error messages
but practically cannot save key-value data

@Service
class RedisRatingService(
private val ratingRepository: RatingRepository,
private val ratingRedisRepository: RatingRedisRepository
) {
fun saveRating(rating: Rating) {
    val logger = LogManager.getLogger(RatingController::class.java)!!
    logger.info(rating)

    ratingRedisRepository.saveRating(rating)
}

